# "If you own" or "If you own a" when talking about a product in an ad

Tags: indefinite-article, zero-article, proper-nouns

Let's say there is a game console called Bumby that can be used to play every single game available.

> 1. "If you own Bumby, you won't need another console."
> 2. "If you own a Bumby, you won't need another console."

In an ad for Bumby, which would be the correct way to say it?

Comment: That depends on the product (Bumby) and not on the word "own", like, if you want to use an article with Bumby

Answer (score -1):

"If you own a Bumby" is correct, because it's a specific thing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. But, a lot of times, don't people say it as #1? Are they just not putting in the "a"?

Comment: They might be using it as if it's a name... As in the case of a pet... As if they are personifying the device...

Comment: you're welcome : D

Comment: @Bumberby: Can you give examples of the usage without an article? I'm having trouble thinking of any such cases where that would make sense.

Comment: That's true. For example, you wouldn't say "If you own iPhone."

Comment: A kid might say "I own Toothless", whereas a grownup might view the dragon figurine as a product and say "she owns a Toothless".

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: This is from Forbes: "So, if you own Tesla, implicitly you are taking Elon's word for it." https://www.forbes.com/sites/greatspeculations/2016/05/10/where-is-teslas-10-q/#2fea7c806812 This is from BetaNews: "If you own iPhone or iPad, wait until Google releases the promised iOS app." https://betanews.com/2012/07/08/nexus-q-first-impressions-review/

Comment: @Bumberby I read those examples as saying "If you own Tesla *products* ", "If you own [Apple] *products* ", more so than saying "If you own *a* Tesla *car*" etc

Comment: @Bumberby: The first of those is definitely "if you own Tesla [*stock*]". Not sure what to make of the other one.

Answer (score -1):

Version one is used to strongly emphasize "Bumby". It is "the one", "the ultimate", "the unique" etc.

Version two is to specify one of many of the same kind, with the same name.

It is (somehow) similar with the difference between:

> 1. I know Toby. *I know **the** Toby your told me about.*
> 2. I know **a** Toby. *I know someone named Toby, but that might not be the same person you referred to. (it implies at least two different persons named Toby)*

Comment: Thank you. So, if you want to emphasize how awesome Bumby is, you would use #1. If you want to say if you own a Bumby you won't need another console and Bumby is awesome because of that, you would use #2. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Both of your example sentences are ungrammatical. You can't *be friend with* someone. You can *be* ***a*** *friend* ***of*** someone or you can *be* ***friendly with*** someone. (And your second, with the article in front of *Toby*, is unnatural in most contexts, even after that correction. Only if you are saying there are multiple Tobys, and you're a friend of one of them, would it make sense.)